# How to load externally hosted data in JSON format

Tags: php

What would the syntax be to pull an external data source, which has the data in JSON format into a variable to be worked with. I understand using json_decode($variable) but how would i load the actual data into that variable for decoding?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If by external you mean that it's hosted on a 3rd-party domain name, then you open a socket and GET the data:

```
$variable = file_get_contents('http://example.com/data.json');
$decoded = json_decode($variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

With `fopen()`, `fread()`, and `fclose()`, or with `file_get_contents()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) ?
(You must have allow_url_fopen true)

Comment: on my test server ive got fopen working but i will need an alternative solution if any for the actual lauch server with the hosting company refusing to support fopen?

Comment: Would cURL be an alternative for a lack of fopen() support?

Comment: I think but I don't know anything about this ^^'

Answer (score 0):

Use anything from fopen + fread to php curl library.
With fopen you could open a remote file if php settings allows you to. I think you should be able to do it now. If you still can't do it, let us know.