# How to use an API to generate a table?

Tags: php, html, api, html-table

There's a game I'm interested in making a widget-type table for on my website.
They have a public API for "`invasions`", located [here](https://www.toontownrewritten.com/api/invasions)

I'm looking to generate a table using that information they provide.  There are number of websites that already use this API and generate a table with the info, such as this [website](http://ttr-invasions.com/)

I know how to make tables that are generated with MySQL data.

However, I've never made a table that is generated with data from an API.

Can someone  get me started?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879865/how-load-externally-hosted-data-in-json-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work. It is up to you to set it up and style it/ structure it as you require it.

```
    $url = "https://www.toontownrewritten.com/api/invasions";
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

    print "<table>";
    foreach ($data->invasions as $title => $inv) {
        print "<tr>";

        print "<td>{$title}</td><td>{$inv->progress}</td><td>{$inv->asOf}</td>";

        print "</tr>";
    }
    print "</table>";
```

---

You could alternatively use something like `curl` to run a http request to fetch the data. It is entirely up to you as to how you implement this.

Comment: Thanks @Darren.  I tried the code [link](http://www.toontownalley.com/ttr-invasions.php) here.  However, it isn't displaying the actual data.  Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Thank you @Darren!  The print_pre($data); actually made it not work, so I removed it and it's working fine now.  :).

Comment: Is there a way to check if there's no data?  Like, I only want it to display the table if there is actually data.  Thanks so much for your help already!

Comment: Something like `if(!empty($data->invasions)) { DO THE FOREACH STUFF }` should work.

Comment: Rofl, thank you @Darren.  I did `if empty($data->invasions)`, no wonder it wasn't working.  oops!  Thank you so much for all of the help you've provided me.  I have one last question.  I've changed the look a bit, see [here](http://www.toontownalley.com/forums/modules/invasions.php).  I added `print "<hr>";`.  Is there a way to add the `print "<hr>";` only if there's more than one "invasion" in progress?  Thanks!

Comment: `if(count($data->invasions) > 1) {ADD THE HR}` should do it :)

Comment: Before seeing your comment, I did `if ($inv[type] > 1) { print "<hr>"; }` just to try it out, and it's seemed to have worked.  I'll use yours instead, though.  Thank you @Darren!  You're the man.

Comment: I'm so sorry to bother you again @Darren, but is there a way to distinguish which "invasion" is the last one? If you go back to that page [here](http://www.toontownalley.com/forums/modules/invasions.php), it's adding the `<hr>` perfectly, but it's adding an `hr` to the last one in the list, as well, which is unnecessary.  Here's the current code!  `if (count(($data->invasions) > 1)) { print "<hr>"; }`  Thanks if you know how to touch this up.

Comment: I did it. :) `if (count(($data->invasions) > 1)) {
        if(end($data->invasions) !== $inv){
  print "<hr>"; } }` Thanks!

Comment: Congrats! Glad all I did helped!.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to use [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to create a dynamic table:

```
$dom = new DOMdocument();
$table = $dom->createElement('table'); // or use: $dom->loadHTML($existing_html);

// Create field values. 
$col1 = clone $col2 = clone $col3 = clone $col4 = clone $col5 = $dom->createDocumentFragment();
$col1->appendXML('<img src="some/image/example.png" />');
$col2->appendXML('<div>example of html within row</div>);
$col3->appendXML('<div>another row</div>');
$col4->appendXML('<div>and another</div>');
$col5->appendXML('<div>last column</div>');
// Note: You can use createElement, instead of appendXML if you don't want to use html inside the columns. 

// Create columns and append content.
$td1 = $dom->createElement('td'); // col1
$td1->appendChild($col1);
$td2 = $dom->createElement('td'); // col2
$td2->appendChild($col2);
$td3 = $dom->createElement('td'); // col3
$td3->appendChild($col3);
$td4 = $dom->createElement('td'); // col4
$td4->appendChild($col4);
$td5 = $dom->createElement('td'); // col5
$td5->appendChild($col5);

// Create row and append columns.
$tr = $dom->createElement('tr');
$tr->appendChild($td1)->setAttribute('class', 'some classes');
$tr->appendChild($td2)->setAttribute('class', 'some classes');
$tr->appendChild($td3)->setAttribute('class', 'some classes');
$tr->appendChild($td4)->setAttribute('class', 'some classes');
$tr->appendChild($td5)->setAttribute('class', 'some classes');

// Append row to table, and table to root document.
$table->appendChild($tr);
$dom->appendChild($table);
$output = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $output;
```